# How to make navigation bar really full width and static

Tags: wordpress, navigation, css

I have absolutely no experience in programming, html, css or anything.
Still, i want to make some kind of website and I'm struggling with several issues right at the beginning.
For starters, my wordpress theme lets me have full width navigation bar without touching any code.
Okay, but i want to have a full width drop shadow effect under the navigation bar. This just doesn't happen and no matter where i try to dig the problem, i just can't do it.
[the link to my website.](http://kalamariwaves.com/)

As you can see, the drop shadow doesn't go full width.
I've seen sites which use the effect so it should be possible. Is it a problem with my theme, should i just forget about it?
(And yeah, the site's really ugly but i'm planning to update it when i have time)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS You need to remove the boxshadow from div id="navigation" and add it to div id="nav-container"

something like this:

```
#nav-container {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
box-shadow: 0 5px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Padding is applied to this div which prevents to display the shadow effect in padding area.

Comment: I tried this one first, and while it seemed to work in the browser while editing the code it didn't work when applied to the custom styles. I just tried to put it before any other custom css and suddenly it started working.. go figure. I had tried this before, hehe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your nav-container div with another div and apply the drop shadow effect to it. After applying the change code looks something like below

```
<div class="shadow">
    <div id="nav-container">
          .....
    </div>
</div>
```

then shadow class in css should be like this

```
.shadow{
    box-shadow: 0 5px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```